# Batch File to Copy and Rename File: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to run a batch file to copy an existing file (to a new location), and then rename the file with the current date and time. For some reason I keep getting an error: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

```
 ::Echo@off
 ::Copy master excel code to a current location
 copy/Y "c:\AAAAA\BBBBB.csv" "S:\CCCCC\BBBBB.csv"
 pause
 ::Rename File to current Date and Time
 FOR /F "tokens=1-11 delims=/: " %%d IN ("%date%:%time%") DO Rename "S:\CCCCC\BBBBB.csv" %%e-%%f-%%g-%%h:%%i:%%j.csv
 pause
```

Change the filepaths for privacy reasons. 
I've tried other people's "fixes" and none seem to work. Any ideas?

Comment: What fixes have you tried? Or do you want to get the same set again, wasting everyone's time including yours?

Comment: check if the file is being open in any editors etc.,

Comment: What is the command that generates the error, `copy` or `rename` ?

Comment: Error occurs on rename. The copy executes fine. I have tried adding: "cd .." as was a suggestion in another post. This had no effect. Also tried adding pause as someone suggested, also did not work.

Comment: You won't be able use the `:` in your file names.

Comment: Wow... Thank you aphoria. Something so simple! Can't believe I didnt see that

Comment: Glad that helped. Are you sure about that error message though? That's not what I get when I attempt to rename a file using illegal characters.

Comment: Well i have run it a number of times and no error message has come up now. I'm not sure why that particular error message was popping up.

Answer (score 0):

:: Mod to suit

@echo off
copy/Y "c:\AAAAA\BBBBB.csv" "S:\CCCCC\BBBBB.csv"

for /f "delims=" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime  ^| find "."') do set"dt=%%a"

set "YY=%dt:~2,2%"

set "YYYY=%dt:~0,4%"

set "MM=%dt:~4,2%"

set "DD=%dt:~6,2%"

set "HH=%dt:~8,2%"

set "Min=%dt:~10,2%"

set "Sec=%dt:~12,2%"

set "sec100_=%dt:~15,3%"

set dtstamp=%YYYY%%MM%%DD%%HH%%Min%%Sec%*%sec100*%

ren "S:\CCCCC\BBBBB.csv" "dim_%dtstamp%.txt"

:end

Comment: Answers are usually better received with some descriptive text and formatting to go with them.

Comment: thank you - new today. Reading and figuring this out :-)

Comment: When I used this method I got "dim_~0,4~4,2~6,2~8,2~10,2~12,2.txt" as the filename.